# Debugging info for authentication in tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

I have a JDBC realm setup and a web-app using basic authentication, but I can't get it to work.  It is putting up the password dialog but it never succeeds.

If I could get the authentication process to spit out some logs, I would be fine.  I have debug="99" in my realm specification but I see nothing getting logged in the usual places.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

localhost.DATE.log

The problem was that my realm was not even being looked at since I had called my context.xml file the wrong thing.